# Помогите получить данные из сокета

Tags: python-3.x, requests, websocket, aiohttp, web-scraping

Здраствуйте, уже несколько дней ломаю голову с тем, как достать данные из сокета. Задача следующая - получать котировки. На сайте нашел сокет из которого приходят данные. [image: на картинке изображен адрес сокета]

Остается подключится к нему , послать нужные запросы и начать слушать. Что я и сделал [image: на картинке код который я написал, проссстая прослушка сокета]
Пробовал и добавлять заголовки, ключи, полученный sid, но ничего не помогло. В результате остановился на коде приведенном выше. Далее смотрел на запросы к сокету и пытался их повторить [image: список запросов к ссокеету и ответов]
Отправляю первый запрос - получаю нужный sid, но во время второго запроса сервер обрывает сойдинение. Как можно решить эту проблему? Прислушаюсь к любым советам, если есть пример подобной работы - буду крайне благодарен

Comment: Ну для начала факт упоминания socket.io намекает, что видимо стоит использовать какой-нибудь socket.io клиент, например [python-socketio](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client.html) и подключаться как-то так `await sio.connect("https://api-fin.po.market/", transports=["websocket"])` — впрочем, что делать после подключения, всё равно не очень понятно

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120)